# Commit is not happening in spring batch job

Tags: db2, spring-batch

I have spring batch job which take unload from DB2 and after doing some process on data again updating , inserting or deleting in DB2 by calling stored proc.

I am not getting any error from SP.

When i checked meta table - `BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION` there I can see `commit-count`but in reality commit is not happening as I am not seeing any data change.

I per my knowledge commit should happen based on chunk size.

Can someone help and let me know what may be the problem?

Please let me know if more information is required

Comment: Please share your configuration

Answer (score 0):

Read the stored procedure source code to see how and when it commits, and specifically how it reacts to errors. If necessary, Debug the stored procedure until you find the first commit happening or not. Check for any evidence of rollbacks (in database monitoring functions, and/or DB2 diagnostics).

Answer (score 0):

Understand that Spring Batch Commit is different than your database commit. Spring batch commit means that processor delivered those chunks to writer after reading from reader and writer method ends successfully , it wouldn't track your record commits to DB i.e. what your writer method is actually updating ( DB tables ).

If Spring Batch Repository meta data looks OK to you and Job & Step statuses look OK to you, there is something wrong in your query and stored procedure.